# chef and test-kitchen synchronizing cookbooks from s3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, test-kitchen

i am using `kitchen-ec2` with `chef-zero` provisioner:

```
$ cat Gemfile | grep kitchen
  gem "test-kitchen", "1.4.2"
  gem "kitchen-ec2", "0.10.0"

$ cat .kitchen.yml | grep require_chef_omnibus
  require_chef_omnibus: true
```

where the current `chef_omnibus` version is `12.4.3-1`.

before posting a pull request over [`kitchen-ec2`](https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-ec2/pulls), i would like to verify whether it is possible to synchronize cookbooks from `s3` (downloading them from `s3` into the ec2 instance), rather then synchronizing the cookbooks by uploading them into each ec2 instance per `suite`?

synchronizing the cookbooks from the local machine to `s3`, and then downloading the cookbooks from `s3` to the ec2 instance -- is drastically much faster and consumes less communication bandwidth.

Comment: Have you considered using a chef server?  It would provide the workflow you're looking for plus a set of Chef specific APIs for managing your cookbooks and other associated Chef entities. Chef server can be configured to use S3 as it's cookbook storage, but I find it scales plenty without going to that bother. Finally you can start with the hosted service provided by Chef, which already runs on Amazon.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor: indeed, i was asking whether such flow can be avoided :) i also fixed my post, i had `chef-solo`, where it should have been `chef-zero`. sorry about that.

Comment: In this case you're using test kitchen. The cookbooks under test are local to the development machine and need to uploaded to the test virtual machine.